# Dask dataframe has no attribute categorize

Tags: python, dataframe, dask, dask-delayed

I am trying to store a Dask dataframe, with a categorical column, to a `*.h5` file per [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ieW3G7ZzRZ0) - 1:23:25 - 1:23:45.

Here is my call to a `store` function:

```
stored = store(ddf,'/home/HdPC/Analyzed.h5', ['Tag'])
```

The function `store` is:

```
@delayed
def store(ddf,fp,c):
    ddf.categorize(columns=c).to_hdf(fp, '/data2')
```

and uses [categorize](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.categorize).

`ddf` and `stored` are of type:

```
print(type(ddf), type(stored))
>>> (<class 'dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame'>, <class 'dask.delayed.Delayed'>)
```

When I run `compute(*[stored])` or `stored.compute()`, I get this:

```
dask.async.AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'categorize'
```

Is there a way to achieve this categorization of the `Tag` column with the `store` function? Or should I use a different method to store the Dask dataframe with a categorical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you try the data-frame operations without the delayed call - daak-dataframes already are lazy compute graphs internally. I believe by calling compute, you are actually passing the resultant pandas data-frame to your function, which is why you get the error.

In your case: simply remove `@delayed` (remembering that to_hdf is a blocking call).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.